# Forcing multiple select changes and then reading the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm relatively new to jquery. I've been banging my head against this issue for a week now trying to figure out a way to do it.

Basically, I have two identical selects that change a displayed number to 1 when selected, and then when changed to a different selection, change that original number back to 0. My original code worked fine, but I wanted to expand the code so that users could save a generated URL and reload their selections at a later date.

Here is the working HTML. Same thing for the second select, only with the ID of ability2.

```
<select id="ability1" onchange="attributeChoice( event )"><option value="selected">Select</option><option value="val1">One</option><option value="val2">Two</option><option value="val3">Three</option><option value="val4">Four</option><option value="val5">Five</option><option value="val6">Six</option></select>
```

And the working jquery

```
function attributeChoice( event ) {

  $( event.currentTarget ).change(function() {
    var attributeChange = this.id;
    var attributeSelect = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');

    $('span#' + attributeSelect).html( 1 );
    $('select#' + attributeChange ).on( 'change', function() {
      $('span#' + attributeSelect).html( 0 );
    });
    getTotals();
  });
}
```

And then this bit of code disables the selected option of the other select so it can't be selected twice.

```
    $('select').change(function() {
      $('select#ability1, select#ability2').not(this).children('option[value=' + this.value + ']').attr('disabled', true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');
      $('select#ability1, select#ability2').not(this).children('option[value=selected]').attr('disabled', true);
    });
```

From what I've read, I need to use a .change() to force the onchange of the select to fire. So far I'm not having any luck. Originally I had the attributeChoice function setup using event.target but I learned that it actually looks all the way back to beginning of what triggered it. I switched over to using this and event.currentTarget instead.

Here is my code I've been toying with. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? (hattr1 is the index of the selected item that is pulled from the URL)

```
$('select#ability1').change(function() {
    $('select#ability1 option').eq(hattr1).prop('selected', true);
    $('select#ability1').change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select a pre-determined `option` in the `select` on the `change` event, call `$.preventDefault()` on the change event, and then use `$.prop()` to select the `option` as you're already doing.

```js
var $select = $('#ability1'),
    hattr1 = 3;

$select.on('change',function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('option').eq(hattr1).prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ability1">
  <option>1</option>
  <option selected>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Michael,

Thanks for the response! Question regarding your answer: Doesn't preventDefault just stop the onchange of the select from firing or am I misunderstanding? I need to get the forced select change to actually fire the onchange so that attributeChoice() performs just as if the user selected it.

Comment: @teaseal I just put that in there for good measure. I commented it out of my answer and it still seems to work so you can take it out if you need to.

Comment: Ok, so I got part of it working. I had to do a slight tweak to your code. It looks like this now:

`var $select = $('select#ability1');
  $select.one('change',function() {
      $('select#ability1 option').eq(hattr1).prop('selected', true);
  }).change();`

I changed on() to one() as on was causing the selects to break. I also added a .change() on the end, otherwise the options were not selecting. So, with that working, the remaining issue is that function attributeChoice, while fired, seems to do nothing. It hits the event.currentTarget and then ends.